# C# Change all Settings files values

Tags: c#, application-settings

I have some forms and have made a Settings File for each that contains

```
int X
int Y
bool FirstRun
```

i save these for the user so that the position of the window is in the same spot every time they start the program. And i was thinking i would add a button to reset them to the standard value.

I found a way to save them to a list with

```
list<Type> settingsList = new list<Type>();
```

then

```
settingsList.Add(typeof(SettingsFileName));
```

But is there a way to make a `foreach` loop to change them all or do i need to do it manualy for them all?

--EDIT--

Left side the minimum a settings file will contain right side all settings files as of now
[image: Settings File Example]

I save files with

```
AdminKontoplanSettings.Default.X = this.Location.X;
AdminKontoplanSettings.Default.Y = this.Location.Y;
AdminKontoplanSettings.Default.Height = this.Height;

AdminKontoplanSettings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing and what is the problem. How do you save the settings? what's in this list? why do you use `Type`? Show more code

Comment: Added a picture of a settings file with minimum settings as well how i save the files. As for code thats about it. That was the only way i could figure to save the settings files in a list i dont know if it is the right way to do it or not

Comment: You'd normally need a different set of settings to store this info for each individual window.  So a for-each isn't going to be very useful, it doesn't help you find the setting name.  Maybe if you give them clever names, like prefixing the form name.   There just isn't much point to code like that, just move the window and close it :)

Comment: @Drago87  Again, it's not clear enough. Where do you read the settings? In each load of a relevant form? Where's the this "back to default" button is? on any form? on the main form?

Comment: @Hans Passant I have a individual settings for each individual window. This should only have been a fale safe if one of the windows got stuck where you cant grab it.

Comment: @Ofir Winegarten. Yes i Read from the settings in each load and save on close. and yes the button could have been on any form but i was thinking on only having it on the main form. As for why its not clear enough is that i don't rely know how to do it. I only know how to save and load from the settings and was looking for a easy way to iterate through all of the setting a value with the same name to a specific value

Comment: So, you'd like to iterate through all the files and reset the values over there?

Comment: Yes that was the intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to iterate through your settings file, you should consider create an interface and let your settings classes inherit from it.
The Settings classes are `partial classes` and you have one part that is controlled  by the designer and one for you (From the designer you have a button "View code" to get to this part of the partial class).

So you interface can look like:

```
internal interface IMySettings
{
    int X { get; set; }
    int Y { get; set; }
    bool FirstRun { get; set; }
    void Save(); 
}
```

The `Save` is to allow the saving operation when iterating.

Your setting file might look like:

```
internal sealed partial class MySettings : IMySettings
```

And then, load all settings to a `List<IMySettings>` field and iterate through them.
The tricky part would be to load them into the list, either you do it with reflection or by hand:

```
var mySettingList = new List<IMySettings> {AdminKontoplanSettings.Default, MySetting.Defalut, AnotherSettings.Default ....}
```

Then, on you "reset" button `onclick` method:

```
foreach (var setting in this.mySettingList)
{
  setting.X = 0;
  setting.Y = 0;
  setting.FirstRun = true;
  setting.Save();
}
```

Comment: This should be what i'm looking for. Need to look in the settingsfiles if it is doable

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure of what you want, but i think this might be help :

```
foreach (Type t in settingList)
{
  t.x = 0;
  t.y = 0;
}
```

This will be change all the positions of your forms.

Comment: That is what i want but when i try the `t.X = 0` i get a `'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'X' and no extension method 'X' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: i have a question : what is SettingsFileName ? it's a attribute ? or a object ? can we have your code ? it will be helpfull to find your problem ;)

Comment: SettingFileName is just that. It is a settings file. I will update the post with a picture of one. As for code i dont realy have any yet. The `list<Type> settingsList = new list<Type>();
settingsList.Add(typeof(SettingsFileName));` is the only way i manage to store the setting file in a list. i dont know if that how i should do it or if there is a better way.